# Blogger restyle header

Tags: css, blogs

Here's my situation:
[image]

The orange area is the header area, the gray areas are title and description.

What's the css or html code to change the orange areas width? I want it to be the same width as the whole page(the light gray area). I have search on this and found that it can be changed by changing the "#header-wrapper" tag, but in my blog I don't have it. Any ideas?

My blog: [free-apple-stuff-free.blogspot.com](http://free-apple-stuff-free.blogspot.com)

Comment: It depends on the HTML structure of the blog page.

Comment: Care to provide a link to your blog? It's tough to visualize without any code.

Comment: @Cobold - Do you wish to spread the orange color to the whole page while keeping the content at the center itself ?

Comment: @Mahesh I just want to change the orange areas width to be the same as the light gray area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the css of `.content-outer` to -

```
.content-outer{ width: 100% }
// Remove the max-width and min-width which are restricting the center content width.
```

This will make the all your page content moving to left since the content is occupying entire width.